# Keep igGrid Filtering settings

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am displaying some data in an Infragistics igGrid. After displaying, I manipulate some of the rows displayed and reload the data. After reloading, the datagrid resets the filter settings. How can I call the data filtering function manually after i reload the data.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to call filtering programmatically.

```
 $(".selector").igGridFiltering("filter", ([{fieldName: "Name", expr: "Adjustable Race", cond: "equals", logic: "OR"}]));
```

See [this link](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2015.2/ui.iggridfiltering) for more details.